# SQL Database Parent/Child recursion

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, recursion, recursive-query

Here is my table:

```
parent_id | child_id
--------------
        1 | 2
        1 | 3
        1 | 4
        2 | 5
        2 | 6
        5 | 8
        8 | 9
        9 | 5
```

I need to get all of the items under parent `2`. I've found a few things similar to this, but but couldn't figure out how to make it work for my case. I keep getting `maximum recursion` limit reached. Here's what I have:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT gt.[child_id]
      FROM [CHSPortal].[dbo].[company_adgroupstoadgroups] gt
     WHERE gt.parent_id='2'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT g.[child_id]
      FROM [CHSPortal].[dbo].[company_adgroupstoadgroups] g
      INNER JOIN CTE g2 on g.parent_id=g2.child_id
)
select distinct child_id from CTE
```

The desired result is going to be: 2,3,4,5,6,8,9.

What modification do I need to make to get a list of all the items under child `2`. I would also prefer `2` (the parent node) to be in the list. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I was wondering if the sample data is real data? Because according to that, you would be implementing infinite recursion. All items under 2 = 5,6. Items under 5 = 8, Items under 8 = 9, Items under 9 = 5, then it goes back to 5,8,9 indefinitely.

Comment: Why not just use one select statement and use a where clause: where parent_id = 2? Also you said you need all items under parent 2 and then you needed all items under child 2 later. What are you looking for?

Comment: @the_pete - The data in the table represents a 'tree', or other recursive structure, and the OP is looking to do [Tree Traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal).  Of course, this particular instance has the noted cyclical data problem.  A simple `SELECT` statement is insufficient for this task - there is a specific syntax required for this type of work, as the existing answers are using.

Comment: I will loop infinitely, but because that is the way the data structure is set up. But it will not keep adding nodes. Once it goes back to a previous value, i don't need it to go any deeper.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is a loop in your example (5|8, 8|9, 9|5), that is why you reach the maximum recursion limit.

Regarding the filtering question,below you can find an example for filtering by root node:

```
;WITH MTree (parent_id, child_id, LEVEL) AS (
    SELECT t.parent_id , t.child_id, 0 AS LEVEL 
    FROM table_1 t
    WHERE child_id = 2 --here you can filter the root node
UNION ALL      
    SELECT m.parent_id , m.child_id, LEVEL + 1
    FROM Table_1 m
        INNER JOIN MTree t ON t.child_id = m.parent_id
)

SELECT * FROM Mtree;
```

Comment: if you would like to exclude the corresponding top row, the use the following filter in the CTE: `WHERE parent_id = 2 --here you can filter the root node`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's wrong with your query, aside from not relating to the sample data you provided, but this works just fine:

```
;WITH src AS (SELECT 1 AS parent_id, 2 AS child_id
               UNION  SELECT 1, 3
               UNION  SELECT 1, 4
               UNION  SELECT 2, 5
               UNION  SELECT 2, 6
               UNION  SELECT 5, 8
               UNION  SELECT 8, 9
               UNION  SELECT 9, 5)
    ,cte AS (SELECT *
             FROM src
             WHERE child_id = 2
             UNION  ALL
             SELECT a.*
             FROM src a
             JOIN cte b
               ON a.parent_id = b.child_id           
            )
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM cte
```

--Limited to top 100 because of infinite recursion problem with sample data.

Comment: The limit does prevent the infinite recursion problem, but the actual data is much larger than 100 enties, and I don't want duplicates. How can I get a distinct list of the values without knowing how much data will return?

Comment: You can set a max recursion factor with `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` adjusting the 0 to a number that makes sense, then add `DISTINCT` to the `SELECT` statement.  However your data is the real problem, you could add a `WHERE` clause that prevents the infinite loop.